# Instruction Case and Right in SQL

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to design a view in SQL Server 2008 R2 and I'm trying to add this column that check the last char of a column in my database

```
CASE RIGHT (LRIGLOT, 1) 
     WHEN 'C' THEN 'CERTIFICATE' 
     ELSE 'NON CERTIFICATE' 
END
```

but if I write it in this way it is corrected by the management in

```
CASE RIGHT ('LRIGLOT. 1') 
    WHEN 'C' THEN 'CERTIFICATE' 
    ELSE 'NON CERTIFICATE' 
END
```

I tried also to put write it manually in the query, but it's not working as I want, it always goes in the else branch.

What I want to do is fill in the column depending on whether the last character of a column is equal to or different from C. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by it is corrected by the management? As in your manager is correcting it? Speak to them then.

Comment: It's not easy to understand exactly what you mean. Please include some sample data and desired results to illustrate.

Comment: As a **side note:** SQL Server 2008 and 2008 R2 reached end of life well over a year ago and are now **completely unsupported**. You really should be looking at upgrading to a supported version.

Comment: If you mean that you're using the view designer and it's changing your code, the simple answer is to stop using the view designer. It's horribly buggy, has been for years, and there's no indication the MS ever plan to fix the bugs. Write a `CREATE` or `ALTER VIEW` statement in a query window instead.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested, the problem was the use of the view designer. I was on the right way when I wrote directly on the query, but I missed to trim the column I was checking. At last the right way to write it was

```
CASE RIGHT (LTRIM(RTRIM(LRIGLOT)) , 1)
    WHEN 'C' THEN 'CERTIFICATE'
    ELSE 'NON CERTIFICATE'
END
```

Comment: LTRIM serves no purpose here. And fyi current versions of sql server support TRIM which removes spaces from both ends of a string.